# Highchart and DWR Comet

Tags: comet, highcharts, dwr

There is an element that get updates using `DWR` comet command in server side 
Like this

```
Util.setValue("newnumber", number);
```

So in Client Side I can get it like in simple command like

```
<div id = newnumber></div>
```

Now I want to add the data in HighCharts' live chart. My question is there any event command that says that the **"newnumber"** value is updated so that I can add the new data in highchart series?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out. 
The only way to get value in dwr

```
var xx = dwr.util.getValue(newnumber);
```

And I used periodic function to get latest value add in series of Highcharts

```
    setInterval(function() {
                            var yy = parseInt(xx);
                            var x = (new Date()).getTime(), // current time
                                y = yy;
                            series.addPoint([x, y], true, true);
                        }, 1000);
```